# Rails 5 - sending data from controller to javascript in json format

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I want to be able to send an array of object to my Google Maps, so I can display the locations.

What I want to ask is what is the best way to do it?
I was trying to use RABL gem but the tutorials they have are not exactly up to date.

Then I found info about building and API using rails. This seems like a good plan, but I have no idea how to use it. Google is filled with tuts but only for building API-only app, and I already have my app and just want to add an API to it.

Where should I start looking for it?

Comment: Simplest is to respond to JSON format in your controller.
You can render a json partial easily with  jbuilder. `https://github.com/rails/jbuilder` . The common way to implement an API in your rails app is to use the `grape` library. `https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape` which is a DSL for writing APIs.

If not using rails 5, you can require the `rails-api` library separately and implement API only controllers. It seems trivial to have controllers inheriting from `ApplicationController::Base` and others from `ApplicationController::API` in the same app but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, in your controller:

```
def something_controller
   @something = YourModel.all
   respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => @something } 
   end
end
```

in your javascript if you are using jQuery:

```
$.getJSON('your_controller/your_action.json', function(data) {
  // and here you can do something with tour json data
  console.log(data)
});
```

Comment: And how exactly am I supposed to use it? I mentioned it in my previous post, but I am a newbie. Started using RoR like 1-2 weeks ago.

Comment: i edited, and added better solution for you

Comment: I also noticed, that respond_to/with are no longer included in rails 5, so after installing a 'responders' gem it works no as expected. Thanks, anyway!

Comment: I tried this, theres no error, but its not logging the data into the console? Completely blank.